# Does anyone have Titanfall up and running on Ubuntu yet?

Tags: games

Seems like Ubuntu is the best OS but the lack of big games is unfortunate. Does anyone got a walkthrough on getting Titanfall specifically up and running on Ubuntu with an Nvidia card?

Answer (score 0):

### It will *most* probably not work

Like many games, Titanfall was programed for Windows. While [someone](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=30177) has tried and succeeded to install with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) he wasn't able to start it. The situation *might* have improved since then... or not.

Setting up and configuring wine for a game isn't for the faint at heart. It's much easier using [PlayOnLinux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux), but I think this won't matter much in this case.

### Personal Note

I play games on Linux all the time, but I stick to the stuff Steam supporting under Linux. For the rest I keep a Windows 7 installation around.

Answer (score 0):

Use lutris, https://lutris.net/ I've personally used it successfully. they have good forums and the community is quick to respond, just remember that dxvk with WINE is a new technology and is improving so don't go into it with expectations that non-native software will work perfectly. Also as you are emulating windows some problems on windows can come with programs to, just follow the instructions.

One more thing, install wine with `sudo apt-get install wine-stable` in a terminal, it's just easier. And install the nvidia drivers with [software and updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiV5A.png) in [additional drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWNWT.png) and install the recommended driver. Hope you understand, and google is your friend.

Answer (score -2):

download wine, it allows you to run all windows binaries i.e programs games,you can download wine through Ubuntu Software Center. Or you can play this game on Play on Linux also available in software center.

or visit [wine HQ](https://www.winehq.org/) for more details

Comment: Not all Windows programs work well under wine. Some don't work at all. Titanfall recieves a "Garbage"-Rating under winehq: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=16017